# Why jQuery.ajax converter did not called?

Tags: jquery, type-conversion, converters

I try to use [`converters`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#extending-ajax)
I have next code:

```
    $.ajax( url, {
        accepts: { dload: 'application/x-dload' },
        contents: { dload: /dload/ },
        converters: {
            'text dload': true,
            'dload json': jQuery.parseJSON,
        },
        dataType: 'dload',
        success: function( data, status, xhr ){
            debugger;
            $( container ).html( 'Done' );
            success();
        },
    })
```

but when I have stopped at `debugger` the `data` variable is plain text.
Why `jQuery.parseJSON` is not called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The converter is called, but "text dload". Because **all responses from server are text**, so 'text dload' converter is called.

`'text dload': true'` means that nothing is called and leaved as is. So I configure my `converters` as next:

```
converters: {
    'text dload': jQuery.parseJSON,
},
```